How best to merge many git branches appending to a single file?
I have a repo with some automation that's failed badly. The automation should retrieve a file from the git repo, append "a record," which is multiple lines, push up a new branch, open a pull/merge request for that branch to be merged to the default, and then automatically merge after a successful CI run. Failure in that last step has left me with 50 open, conflicting MRs.
Essentially, each branch's changes are to a single file, simply appending data to it. So, each of the branches' changes are in conflict with each other: git merge $(git branch --remote | grep ${BRANCH_PREFIX}) using the octopus merge strategy fails. I could merge them one at a time in chronological order, a task I've undertaken when I've had a handful of failures but resolving 50 is an afternoon instead of a cup of coffee.
Ideally, I'm looking for the best way to effectively end up with the contents of the change of each branch appended in chronological order. The branch name has a timestamp in it, if that helps more than a commit timestamp. There's not really a record separator per say: it's a text format but the processing tool doesn't really have a "get last" that'd be meaningful to iterate through the branches and call the tool to get the last record and then dump it in a file.
I'd like to preserve the git history, but I'm OK with losing it, too.

Merge, remove conflict markers, stage, commit? Conflict markers should be pretty easy to detect with a regex (^(<<<<<<<|=======|>>>>>>>))

Don't use single text file as a shared database. Don't use GIt as a DBMS or distribution tool. The best solution for your task would be a real database, one row per record. If you still want Git — at least use one file with timestamp per record; concatenate the files not on every write but before feeding the concatenated result into the target program.

@phd Alas, there's no "real" database software that meets the needs of this particular application and one record per file gets unwieldy quickly. https://ledger-cli.org/doc/ledger3.html#Fat_002dfree-Accounting Although, I'm really thinking about handling ingest in single files then manually condensing to the main if this error breaking CI persists.

@ColinDean IMO any SQL database will do. One table, 3 columns — autoincrement id, timestamp, text of the record. When you need to feed the concatenated text to the ledger — SELECT text FROM records ORDER BY id, concatenate and pass down the line.
